# How to get pwd relative path in bash without first slash

Tags: bash, relative-path, pwd

I am writing a small Bash script to do some automatic commands. In particular , i would like to get relative path without first '/' in pwd

```
pwd : Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop
```

insted of

```
pwd : \Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop
```

i'm new to bash and dont know how to do it

Comment: The first character in your example is not /, but \.

Comment: Note that removing the first character from the output from `pwd` does not yield a relative path to your working directory, but the path of your working directory relative to your root directory. This is pretty pointless; are you sure you want to have this?

Comment: Is `pwd` **really** printing a path with backslashes ```\``` instead of forward slashes ```/``` on your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I don't see much practical use for getting your working directory path with the first charcter removed, but if you want to have it, you can do it by `${PWD:1}`, i.e.

```
echo "${PWD:1}"
```

Comment: to get relative path of any file that imported in the terminal

`read -p "Wordlist : " path

wordlistpath="${path//"/mnt$(pwd)"}"
relativepath="${wordpath:1}"`